# Spring Boot web socket has issues while sending messages for the first time

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to create a chat application with spring boot web socket. The implementation is completed with spring boot and my Angular 7 app is connecting to this. The issue I face is, when i connect to the socket for the very first time after server reboot or so, the first 5-6 messages to the socket are not sent. From then on it works flawlessly and super fast. What is it that I am missing?

I am implementing WebSocketConfigurer and trying to use registerWebSocketHandlers to connect to /socket/*/* where i pass my user id and conversation id to initiate the chat similar to /socket/1/2.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSocket
 public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketConfiguration.class);

 @Bean
 public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new 
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
    container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024000);
    return container;
 }

 @Bean
 public SessionHandler sessionHandler() {
    return new SessionHandler();
 }

 @Override
 public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry 
 registry){
    registry.addHandler(sessionHandler(), 
 "/socket/*/*").setAllowedOrigins("*");
 }
}
```

Expect the system to transport messages flawlessly from message 1. But it is perfect after the first few messages.

Comment: Have you considered using the higher-level web socket messaging support, instead of the rather low-level WebsocketHandler interface? https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Other than that, there's not enough information to solve this problem. Have you checked the logs, have you checked the JavaScript console, have you inspected the network traffic between browser and server, e.g. with your browser's developer tools?